# Wimshurst Machine Neutralizing/Shorting Bars

Tags: electrostatics

Are these connected electrically?  I picked up a [Wimshurst machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wimshurst_machine) at an auction (broken support), and the bars are mounted on a metal shaft.  Seems to me the bars should be electrically isolated from each other.